# Is there a way to send commands to screened process?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnu-screen

I have a process, that automatically starts up with server using this command -

```
screen -dmSL myserver sudo bash /myserver/start
```

I can stop the process if I connect to the screen with `screen -x myserver` and enter `stop` command.

Now, say I have a script `/myserver/stop`, how would it work? It won't work with following contents:

```
screen -x myserver
stop
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimenting here's the answer I found. This is the command that I will use:

```
screen -p 0 -S myserver -X eval "stuff stop\015"
```

Now point by point:

`-S` says to connect to screen session `myserver`

`-p` specifies that message goes to window 0 in seession

`-X` is argument that allows you to send commands to screen session without entering it yourself

`eval` tells to print "stop" and a newline to the application's stdin

Comment: what if I didn't name the process "myserver" or anything?